# Estimating rates of convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-optimization

If I have a set of data points obtained from a numerical approximation say

15.3828
15.2458
15.2095
15.2003

how can I estimate the rate of convergence?

Comment: They're eigenvalues corresponding to matrix systems of increasing size. So the grid size of the problem is being refined 16x16, 32x32 etc

Comment: It corresponds to the solution of a PDE, where the grid size is being refined at successive steps. I only need an estimate of the rate at which it is converging rather than a definite answer. It seems straightforward but for some reason im struggling with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these are successive approximations after $k$ steps, and the assumption is that each step reduces the absolute error by a factor of $\alpha < 1$, then you'd expect $$
  \frac{\left|x_{k+1} - x\right|}{\left|x_k - x\right|} = \alpha \text{,}
$$
where $x$ is the true value.

For a sequence of approximations $x_0,\ldots,x_N$, you could assume that $x_N$ is the true value. Then you'd expect that $$
  \left|x_k - x_N\right| = \left|x_0 - x_N\right|\alpha^k
$$
meaning that you can find $\alpha$ by fitting the function $$
  k \to \left|x_0 - x_N\right|\alpha^k
$$ to the $(x,y)$-pairs $$
  (1, \left|x_1 - x_N\right|), \ldots, (N-1, \left|x_{N-1} - x_N\right|)
$$

---

Since your approximations seems to be the result of varying some mesh size, you need to adjust this approach a bit. If the approximation $x_k$ corresponds mesh width $h_k$, we'd expect $$
  |x_k - x| = C(h_k)^\alpha \text{.}
$$

Again assuming that $x_0,\ldots,x_N$ is a series of approximations, this time for mesh widths $h_0,\ldots,h_N$, you'd then fit this function to the $(x,y)$-pairs $$
  (h_0, \left|x_0 - x_N\right|), \ldots, (h_{N-1}, \left|x_{N-1} - x_N\right|) \text{.}
$$

Since $\ln |x_k - x| = \alpha\ln C + \alpha\ln h_k)$, one can instead use linear regression  on the $(x,y)$-pairs $$
  (\ln h_0, \ln \left|x_0 - x_N\right|), \ldots, (\ln h_{N-1}, \ln \left|x_{N-1} - x_N\right|) \text{.}
$$

If I do this with MATLB (using `polyfit`) I find $\alpha \approx 2.2$.

Comment: Could I calculate it using:

$k=\frac{ \ln \left( \frac{ x_{n+1}}{x_{n}} \right)}{\ln \left( \frac{ x_{n}}{x_{n-1}} \right)}.$

Comment: Thankyou! much appreciated